# MeshLab: How to import XYZRGB file

Tags: colors, textures, meshlab

When I import and XYZRGB (that I generate programatically), MeshLab renders the point-cloud, but the colors are missing.  How can I assign textures/colors to vertices.  I have tried "Vertex Attribute Transfer" but nothing happens.

Comment: I am having the same problem. Unfortunately, this question has no answers yet.

Answer (score 8):

Rename the extension .xyz to .txt. Then choose the x y z r g b option when importing the file. in meshlab

source: http://www.laserscanningforum.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=168&t=8052