# How do I read xyzrgb file and use rgb for color into MeshLab

Tags: cloud, rgb, point, xyz

I have a file I created from an image file that I'm trying to use into MeshLab.  At each pixel the file contains, in comma delimited form, the x coordinate value, y coordinate value, z computed value - between 0-100, r color value, g color value, and b color value.  Each pixel's information is on a separate line of the file with line end "\n" except for the last pixel.

When I read the file in with an extension of .txt, I see the image information displayed but there is no color data shown.  I looked at [MeshLab: How to import XYZRGB file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22850905/meshlab-how-to-import-xyzrgb-file) and then https://laserscanningforum.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=8052 but can't see examples.

Does someone have the secret?

Is there another 3D point cloud display program that will do this?

Thanks,
RONC

Answer (score 1):

I found after trying many things, I started from scratch and when you Import Mesh, there is an option to choose the format and how it is interpreted.  Look for XYZRGB.  It is that simple.

RONC